# Transaction pending on Etherscan but not showing on Metamask

Tags: transactions, metamask

I tried to speed up and cancel from Metamask but it disappeared from the there and still showing on Etherscan like pending https://etherscan.io/tx/0x178a435501bfe9e4eda4dc3dc47708a3756148c2aac76e340534c18e728f25f9

Tried to send a tx offline with the same Nonce but it keeps giving an error.
Is there anything else I can do to cancel the txs?
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Never-mind, all went through after about 24 hours. With a very low fee actually. Strange that on Metamask this tx was showing confirmed while it wasn't on the block